# PropertyName must be set to a valid property name of the control named 'ListOfPosts' in ControlParameter 'SubcategoryId'

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Hi I am trying to create a SQLDataSource with a parameter that has the value of a query string but I keep getting an error that says :

PropertyName must be set to a valid property name of the control named 'ListOfPosts' in ControlParameter 'SubcategoryId'

I can not seem to understand what the propertyName should be.Here is my code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ListOfPosts" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" 
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [forum_posts].[PostTitle], [forum_posts].[PostContent], [forum_posts].[PostDate],
    aspnet_Users.Username , forum_subcategories.SubCategoryName
    FROM [forum_posts]
    JOIN aspnet_Users ON [forum_posts].UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId
    JOIN forum_subcategories on forum_posts.SubcategoryId = forum_subcategories.SubCategoryID
    WHERE [forum_posts].SubcategoryId = @SubcategoryId">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="SubcategoryId" ControlID="ListOfPosts" Type="String" DefaultValue='<%= Request.QueryString["post"] %>'/>
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `asp:QueryStringParameter` that you can use instead. The `asp:ControlParameter` is meant to be used with controls in your page and if such control does not exist you get the error you were getting

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="SubcategoryId" Type="String" querystringfield="post"/>
</SelectParameters>
```

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.querystringparameter.aspx

Others are ControlParameter,
CookieParameter,
FormParameter,
ProfileParameter,
SessionParameter